# How to manually Destroy an IntentService and Destroy it When App Close

Tags: android, intentservice

I am new to `IntentServices`.  I am using My `IntentSevice` to perform background webservices call. My application requires the user to sign in...
when the user signs in, the `IntentService` is started and in the `onHandleIntent` method I declared a `TimerTask` that runs every amount of minutes (please inform me if its the best solution to periodically perform a task in `IntentService`).
My question is, how can I stop the `IntentService` from periodically executing if the application was closed or the user signs out.

what I tried: 
when the user signs out, i am cancelling the timer task. and so the webservices calls stop, but i don't know how to properly do that in case the application force quits (should i handle this or  the `IntentService` will stop by itself in my case). also is cancelling the timer enough? (when the user signs in again, the `IntentService` will be called again so is that good?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use the stopping method whenever you want to stop the service.
When ever you want to stop service just use "stopSelf();" method with in the service class.
By the way,the background services automatically destroyed when the application is removed from Ram.But You want to end the service with in the application then use "stopSelf();" method.
I hope this will help you.

Comment: is it enough to call on stopself() or should i also cancel the TimerTask?

Comment: Timer Task should also be canceled manually.Otherwise it will crash your app.Always end the unnecessary  processes for good programming practice.

Comment: Thank you.. i just have one more question.. i logged the OnDestroy method in the IntentService and noticed that OnDestroy is being called initially (though the Service is executing afterwards) do you know why..?

Comment: Check your onBind method.What is its return value.

Comment: Android does not like to run useless services.So Android OS automatically ends useless Services.Services becomes useless when they are not returning any value or any notification to user.If you want to stop the service from calling onDestroy().Then,set the return value of overridden method onStartCommand() to "START_STICKY".It will automatically start the service again and again unless the service is stopped forcefully.